# Windows Server2008 RemoteApps - Starting but not handing over windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, remoteapp

At work we run a windows 2008 server and we roll out Remote Apps for all the applications that out employees use. So far they are working wonderfully with very little issues but there is one problem that props up every once and while that we cant seem to shake.

We have an issue where the application after being left alone for a while stops responding instead of falling back to the login box. When this happens we go "No Biggie" and ALT + F4 the application and start it again.

Then after the application has loaded as you can see when u click on details it doesn't hand over the window to the user it just stays in its loading box. You are actually able to use the application while it is loading because it is fully loaded.

The only solution we have currently is remoting into the server and killing all processes being used by the user and starting them again.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and/or knows the solution.

Comment: Can this happen to any, or is it one specific application that has the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if there is a time-out feature you can enable.  Don't know if it will be useful to you.  This MS blog seems pretty informative:  http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2007/09/28/terminal-services-remoteapp-session-termination-logic.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is the RDP pointing to the actual executable or to a loader such as a batch file the passes commands/options? We have an app that sometimes does not pop and remains in the details pane of the 'Starting RemoteApp' window. Unfortunately, this occurs even when a new user session is created and is not caused by leftovers from a previous user session so the link provided by rmwetmore would not help.

My thoughts are that it has something to do with the batch we use to load the program. What is your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Does the application throw up any errors? Is there anything in the Application/System log that could point to a possible issue? Maybe the app has some sort of memory leak. Also is this x32 or x64 system?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if Terminal Services Configuration has Disconnect timeout set? It's sounds like the session for these remote application has disconnected, leaving client in nonresponsive state.